# Interpolating a 2D array given value of certain points

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a 2D array of that represents the signal strength of a network, like so:

```
d = np.array([[ 0,  0,  0,  3],
              [ 0,  2,  0,  3],
              [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
              [ 0,  0,  0,  3]])
```

I know the signal strength of specific transmission nodes in the network, and the ones I don't know will default to 0. The rules for the network strength is that for every node travelled by the signal, the signal strength decays by 1, and I should get

```
d = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
              [ 1,  2,  2,  3],
              [ 0,  1,  1,  2],
              [ 0,  1,  2,  3]])
```

as a result. What would be the best way to obtain the 2nd array from the first?

Comment: Is the curve linear? Then that should be pretty easy, and there must be quite a few tutorials and other sites describing the math needed all over the Internet.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Can you recommend one? I tried to search up on the interpolation but the ones I saw with scripy interpolate seems to have rather weird results that doesn't match what I need.

Comment: Scipy interpolation isn't needed, just ordinary math. Haven't you ever interpolated a line in a graph in school?

Comment: I mean I probably can come up with something that manually checks and updates the cells one by one, but it's python we're talking about and this is gonna be used for machine learning, so I would prefer a naive solution to be last resort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're not interpolating, but instead applying a max of the effects from each station. Extend to a three dimensional matrix where the added dimension is the number of stations, and then do a max over that dimension. The following produces the same output (made non-square to avoid transposition errors):

```
import numpy as np

input_stations = np.array((
    ( 0,  0,  0,  3),
    ( 0,  2,  0,  3),
    ( 0,  0,  0,  0),
    ( 0,  0,  0,  3),
    ( 0,  0,  0,  0),
))
coords = input_stations.nonzero()
stations = input_stations[coords]
station_y, station_x = input_stations.nonzero()
m, n = input_stations.shape

# stations by y by x
station_strengths = np.clip(
    stations[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
    - np.abs(
        np.arange(m)[np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis] - station_y[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
    )
    - np.abs(
        np.arange(n)[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :] - station_x[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
    ),
    a_min=0, a_max=None,
)
strengths = station_strengths.max(axis=0)

expected = np.array((
    ( 0,  1,  2,  3),
    ( 1,  2,  2,  3),
    ( 0,  1,  1,  2),
    ( 0,  1,  2,  3),
    ( 0,  0,  1,  2),
))

assert np.all(expected == strengths)
```